# Get view height when part of the view is off screen?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-view

Let's say I have a view structure like

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <CustomViewLayout>
        ...
        ...
    </CustomViewLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

This is simplified but I use the above in a bottom sheet and I sometimes change the height of the `ConstraintLayout` and the peek height of the bottom sheet depending on my `CustomViewLayout` height. My problem is that if part of the `CustomViewLayout` is cut off, that is - it is somewhat outside the screen because the `ConstraintLayout` isn't high enough - I'm no longer able to get a correct "full height" of it. I always only seem to get the visible part on screen of the view in that case.

So how can I get the full height of a view that is partly off screen?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I should add that what I've tried is a `globalLayoutListener`, as well as a `customViewLayout.post {}` (and the usual `customViewLayout.height` of course). But none of these measure the full height when part of the view is outside the screen.

Comment: try view.getMeasuredHeight()/Width()

Comment: @ZaidMirza interesting, but I can't see why that would work :) ?

Answer (score 2):

To check my previous answer, I developed a test project to examine the exact situation. It was successful to measure layout height when some part of it is outside of screen (layout height measured **4231px** where the screen height was **1920px**). If the view is long enough that is not completely shown by the screen, you should put it in a scrollable view. So I put the `customViewLayout` in a `NestedScrollView` to consume residual scroll amount after the bottom sheet has expanded. Here is the code and result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutBottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/customViewLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/stateTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sizeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="24dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contentTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:padding="24dp"
                    android:text="@string/lorem"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        customViewLayout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                customViewLayout.viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)
                val height = customViewLayout.measuredHeight
                val width = customViewLayout.measuredWidth
                sizeTextView.text = "Height: $height px                Width: $width px"
            }
        })

        val sheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layoutBottomSheet)
        sheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, offset: Float) {
            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
                when (newState) {
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN -> stateTextView.text = "State: Hidden"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> stateTextView.text = "State: Expanded"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> stateTextView.text = "State: Collapsed"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING -> stateTextView.text = "State: Dragging"
                    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING -> stateTextView.text = "State: Settling"
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**Screen:**

[image]

Comment: Your probably on the right track with having to put the view in a `ListView`, that's great! I'll try it the next week and I'll make sure to get back to you if it works. But I do believe it should work :). Thanks in the meantime!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the view width and height, try this:

```
mCustomViewLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mCustomViewLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            int height = mCustomViewLayout.getMeasuredHeight()
            int width = mCustomViewLayout.getMeasuredWidth()
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't help.. That just makes sure we take the measurement when the view has been laid out, but it still measures "wrong" if part of the view is outside the screen. I should probably add to the question that I've already tried this :)